# Create New Expression from Existing Expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees, expression

I have an `Expression<Func<T,DateTime>>` I want to take the DateTime part of the expression and pull the Month off of it. So I would be turning it into a `Expression<Func<T,int>>` I'm not really sure how to do this. I looked at the [ExpressionTree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) but I can't get it to work like I need. Here is an example of the DateTime Expression

[DateTimeExpression http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/6545/datetimeexpression.png](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/6545/datetimeexpression.png)

Here is an example of what I want to create
[MonthExpression http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/8013/datetimemonthexpression.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/8013/datetimemonthexpression.png)

It looks like I need to create a new MemberExpression that is made up of the Month property from the DateTime expression but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where can i get the Expression Tree Viewer you are using ? Does it work for Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: It comes with the Linq samples. There is a good example of using it here http://linqinaction.net/blogs/jwooley/archive/2008/08/24/enabling-the-expression-tree-visualizer-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx I haven't tried it in Studio 2010 but I know it works in 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you want - and using [`Expression.Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.property.aspx) is the easiest way to do that:

```
Expression func = Expression.Property(existingFunc.Body, "Month");
Expression<Func<T, int>> lambda = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(func, existingFunc.Parameters);
```

I believe that should be okay. It works in this simple test:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Person
{
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person jon = new Person 
        { 
            Birthday = new DateTime(1976, 6, 19)
        };

        Expression<Func<Person,DateTime>> dateTimeExtract = p => p.Birthday;
        var monthExtract = ExtractMonth(dateTimeExtract);
        var compiled = monthExtract.Compile();
        Console.WriteLine(compiled(jon));
    }

    static Expression<Func<T,int>> ExtractMonth<T>
        (Expression<Func<T,DateTime>> existingFunc)
    {
        Expression func = Expression.Property(existingFunc.Body, "Month");
        Expression<Func<T, int>> lambda = 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(func, existingFunc.Parameters);
        return lambda;
    }                                        
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Jon.